# Row count base on Date criteria

Tags: dax, rowcount

Currently, I am facing an issue in a date difference calculation. I need your suggestions on how I can solve this issue. I need to count rows if the value exists between my date slicer range.
In the screenshot provided:

1. "Date of Admission-SNF" is the column I want to count.
2. "MaxSelectedDate" represents the maximum date in my date slicer.
3. "MinSelectedDate" represents the minimum date in my date slicer.
4. In the "SNF Admitted" column, I want to display the result value if "Date of Admission-SNF" falls between "MaxSelectedDate" and "MinSelectedDate."

I am using Dax Formula  as below:

SNF Admitted = COALESCE(
CALCULATE(
COUNTROWS('Patient Tracking'),
FILTER(
'Patient Tracking',
'Patient Tracking'[Date of Admission- SNF (If Applicable)] >= [MinSelectedDate] &&
'Patient Tracking'[Date of Admission- SNF (If Applicable)] <= [MaxSelectedDate]
)
),
0
)

[image]

Comment: Please provide the dax expression being used for `MinSelectedDate` & `MaxSelectedDate` measures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got solution for my issue. basically there were not need to use slicer range manually in DAX. I have use below code and got solution.

COUNTROWS(
FILTER(
'Patient Tracking',
'Patient Tracking'[Date of Admission- SNF (If Applicable)] >= MIN('Table'[Date]) &&
'Patient Tracking'[Date of Admission- SNF (If Applicable)] <= MAX('Table'[Date])
)
)

in above code
"'Patient Tracking'[Date of Admission- SNF (If Applicable)]"    data date column to whom i was calculating and  "'Table'[Date]"  is my Period or Date table